# How to use Regex in Python 3 to identify an uppercase invite code from a string of text?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have been having a lot of trouble trying to identify an invite code from a block of text. I have been able to identify the invite code using regex when it contains only capital letters but not with letters and numbers.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```py
import re

text = "Here's an invite code: DG723BDA8."
matched = []
matches = re.findall(r"(\b(?:[A-Z]+[a-z]?[A-Z]*|[A-Z]*[a-z]?[A-Z]+)\b(?:\s+(?:[A-Z]+[a-z]?[A-Z]*|[A-Z]*[a-z]?[A-Z]+)\b)*)",text)

for match in matches:
    matched.append(match)

inviteCode = matched[0]
```

This code can identify invite codes such as WEVFAAJVF and then selects the first one, but not codes which contain numbers. So to clarify, in an ideal scenario:

"Here's an invite code: ASHDhja, enjoy!" - would return nothing.
"Here's an invite code: WSHSJH, enjoy!" - would return WSHSJH.
"Here's an invite code: BJF4A723, enjoy!" - would return BJF4A723.
"Here's an invite code: asdh32d, enjoy!" - would return nothing.
"Here's an invite code: 172DFHADD, enjoy!" - would return 172DFHADD.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So there always must be an uppercase char present? Is there a minimum amount of characters? Or are they always at the end of the string? This would also match a single uppercase char `\b[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*\b` https://regex101.com/r/IMVcoN/1

Comment: If it's always at the end of the string, you could simply use `\b[A-Z\d]+(?=\.$)`

Comment: Sorry, the example codes I gave were misleading, they aren't always 8 characters long. They are usually a minimum of 5.

Comment: If there must be at least 2 or more try `\b(?=[A-Z0-9]{2,}\b)[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*\b`   https://regex101.com/r/WoqxIK/1 or update the quantifier to the required amount.

Comment: Sorry, I changed some of the codes so they weren't all 8 characters and I forgot to change the resultants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a positive lookahead `(?=` to make sure there are at least 2 chars A-Z0-9 (Or adjust the quantifier to your requirement)

Then use quantifiers `*` matching 0 or more times A-Z0-9 before and after matching at least a single A-Z.

```
\b(?=[A-Z0-9]{2,}\b)[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*
```

In parts

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[A-Z0-9]{2,}\b` Match 2 or more times A-Z or 0-9
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[A-Z0-9]*` Match 0+ times A-Z0-9
- `[A-Z]` Match at least 1 times A-Z
- `[A-Z0-9]*` Match 0+ times A-Z0-9

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OksiR6/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/SCg5WX)

Using the example code:

```
import re

text = "Here's an invite code: DG723BDA8."
matched = []
matches = re.findall(r"\b(?=[A-Z0-9]{2,}\b)[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*\b",text)

for match in matches:
    matched.append(match)

inviteCode = matched[0]
print(inviteCode)
```

Output

```
DG723BDA8
```